# How to return list index by certain value in the list?

Tags: r, api

Let's say I have created a list like that:

```
y <- split(USArrests , USArrests$Murder)
```

How can I return index on the list that contains certain value in this list:

For example: 
In one of the list items (2.7), rape is equal 14.9

How can I return the 2.7 value or index here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is already splitted you can do

```
names(y)[sapply(y, function(x) any(x$Rape == 14.9))]
#[1] "2.7" "6.3"
```

Without spliting the data this would just become simple subset

```
USArrests$Murder[USArrests$Rape == 14.9]
```

---

We can also use `Filter`

```
names(Filter(function(x) any(x$Rape == 14.9), y))
```

and a variation using `purrr::keep`

```
names(purrr::keep(y, ~any(.$Rape == 14.9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply` with `%in%`

```
names(y)[sapply(y, function(x) 14.9 %in% x$Rape)]
#[1] "2.7" "6.3"
```

---

Or with `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map_lgl(y, ~ 14.9 %in% .x$Rape) %>% 
     which %>% 
     names
#[1] "2.7" "6.3"
```